# Stack Exchange runs on ASP.NET MVC3 - Does it use dependency injection, and if so, which container does it use?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, architecture

Which, if any, DI container does Stack Exchange use? Some highlights of the architecture can be seen [here](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html) and [here](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/02/11/stack-exchanges-architecture-in-bullet-points/).

Comment: You don't really have to explain to us what a DI container is, and I don't think they use a specific DI container, or if they do, it's homegrown.

Comment: @jcolebrand - If you do not know, then why comment? I did not "explain what a DI container is", those links to the architecture are for stack exchange, not DI containers. Please read and examine before posting speculations.

Comment: @jcolebrand: speculation is best left for gold^H^H^H^Hrep mining.

Comment: You're right, my apologies, and I'll leave the comment for my own shaming. However, let me just mention to you, that they've been rather explicit in all their code, and the DataExplorer has a public repo on google code, and there is not, that I'm aware, a DI layer there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We do not currently make specific use of a DI container. We try to keep things minimal, and only introduce complexity/abstractions if it solves a problem we **actually have**. We are also, however, very happy to refactor - so if/when we felt that this would be a beneficial thing, we'd very happily hack it in.

We *do* keep our code pretty DRY, particularly around the key object constructions, so this wouldn't necessarily be too tricky.